Jupyter lab file failing to open
I should preface by saying that I'm pretty clueless about this. Recently, I tried to open Jupyter notebook using an Ubuntu terminal, and got ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND. I cant find the jpserver-XXXX-open.html file at the given directory and, while I'm not certain, I cant seem to find the file anywhere else either, so I don't think that its opening at all. Also, the directory it gives seems completely made up:
file:///home/samfr/.local/share/jupyter/runtime/jpserver-1003-open.html
I cant find a .local anywhere. I've tried all basic stuff, and it should be noted that I didn't do anything to make this happen in the first place, but have since fiddled around with things. Any help would be appreciated, though there's a good chance I'm just being naive.
tried:
-restarting
-making a new environment
-reinstalling Ubuntu
-changing the port
-deactivating firewalls

Is your ubuntu username samfr? If so, then we are on the right track. .local is likely a folder in your home directory. On the command line you can do a cd /home/samfr/.local or cd ~/.local if your into the whole brevity thing, and see if it pops you into the directory. The . at the beginning means it's "hidden" so you won't see it with an ls unless you provide the -a flag and Ubuntu's filemanager UI may not show it unless you toggle the setting to show hidden files. That doesn't solve your problem, but it may help with next steps of troubleshooting.
